# Matching between angle brackets in Bash in Cygwin 2.4.1(0.293/5/3)

Tags: regex, bash

I have:

```
file=something.xml

IFS='
'
for i in $( cat $file )
do
    if [[ $i =~ '>[^<]*<' ]]
    then
       echo $i | sed -e 's/.*>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/g'
    fi
done
```

The match in the if finds nothing.

If I then do:

```
file=something.xml

IFS='
'
for i in $( cat $file )
do
    #if [[ $i =~ '>[^<]*<' ]]
    #then
       echo $i | sed -e 's/.*>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/g'
    #fi
done
```

Of course, every line of the file passes through the sed.  Lines that match the pattern in the sed are correctly filtered by the sed.

So the regex in the sed is matching but not the regex in the if, even though the two regexes are exactly the same.

Can someone explain this?  I'm a longtime, though casual, Bash user, so I may not be doing things according to best practices.

Comment: Use an XML parser to process XML, not line-oriented tools like `sed`. XML is not a regular language.

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over the contents of a file.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting with cygwin and regex, I found that the apostrophes are problematic here. Instead using apostrophes, we can escape the `>` and `<` chars:

```
if [[ $i =~ \>[^\<]*\< ]]
```

I don't know if we can make it work with some sort of quotes too. However, this seems to be simple enough for this script.